# Bound DataGridView not updating first row as expected (other rows fine)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I succeeded in creating a reusable **DataGridView** windows form that allows end users to sort, add/remove columns, multi-column filtering and saves the settings to apply on next program run. I succeeded, however...

I used an unbound DGV for user data entry/editing because I use row 0 for the column filtering string(s) as I understand I cannot add such a row to a bound DGV.

To update the sql table I'm mirroring the unbound DGV with a bound DGV and updating the bound DGV on each cell edit. The bound DGV (on screen during dev, will be hidden once completed) accurately reflects a mirror copy of the data from the unbound DGV 100% of the time.

On saving, the first row in the bound DGV will not update table unless I change the data **in 2 cells**, if I change value in just **one cell** it does not save. **On any other row it works without any issues even if I only change one cell**, just that first row will not update if only one cell changed. Been searching all day for solution, tried many things and I'm still at a loss on how to get that first row to save correctly if only one cell has been updated.

Has anyone any ideas why?

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  data1connection = New SqlConnection(cConn)
  data1ds.Clear()
  data1connection.Open()
  data1adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Me.SQLQ, data1connection)
  data1adapter.Fill(data1ds)
  data1connection.Close()
  DGVBound.DataSource = data1ds.Tables(0)
  DGVBound.ClearSelection()

  Using conn As New SqlConnection(cConn)
     Dim command As New SqlCommand(Me.cSQLQ, conn)
     conn.Open()
     Dim RS As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

     'set column headers
     DGVUnbound.ColumnCount = RS.FieldCount()
     Dim f = RS.FieldCount() - 1
     For x = 0 To f
        DGVUnbound.Columns(x).Name = RS.GetName(x)
     Next x

     'add blank filter row
     Dim myList As New List(Of String)()
     For x = 0 To f
        myList.Add("")
     Next x
     Dim myArray As String() = myList.ToArray()
     DGVUnbound.Rows.Add(myArray)
     DGVUnbound.Rows(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige

     'add rows of data
     While RS.Read()
        myList = New List(Of String)()
        For x = 0 To f
           myList.Add(RS(x).ToString)
        Next x
        Dim myArray1 As String() = myList.ToArray()
        DGVUnbound.Rows.Add(myArray1)
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
     End While
  End Using

  LoadUserPrefs()
  AddHandler DGVUnbound.ColumnWidthChanged, AddressOf SaveUserPrefs
  AddHandler DGVUnbound.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged, AddressOf SaveUserPrefs    
End Sub

Sub Mirror() Handles DGVUnbound.CellValueChanged
  If DGVUnbound.CurrentRow.Index <> 0 Then
     Dim cColValue = DGVUnbound.CurrentCell.Value
     Dim cColName = DGVUnbound.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name
     Dim cKeyValue = DGVUnbound.CurrentRow.Cells(DGVUnbound.Columns.Item(Me.cKeyCol).Index).Value
     Dim x = DGVBound.Columns.Item(cColName).Index

     For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVBound.Rows
        If row.Cells(DGVBound.Columns.Item(Me.cKeyCol).Index).Value = cKeyValue Then
           'update cell
           DGVBound.ClearSelection()
           DGVBound.Rows(row.Index).Cells(x).Selected = True

           DGVBound.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
           DGVBound.BeginEdit(True)
           row.Cells(DGVBound.Columns.Item(cColName).Index).Value = cColValue
           DGVBound.EndEdit()
           DGVBound.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
           'Next line fixed issue:
           DGVUnbound.Select
        End If
     Next
  End If
 End Sub

Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
  data1cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(data1adapter)
  data1changes = data1ds.GetChanges()
  If data1changes IsNot Nothing Then
     data1adapter.Update(data1changes)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I found solution. Added to end of cell editing procedure:
DGVUnbound.Select
Now all works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically switching focus back to DGVUnbound via a DGVUnbound.Select() fixed issue. Updated code above to reflect.